# Huge cache_menu table

Tags: 7, caching

My Drupal database becomes very huge, it just related to cache_menu table:

```
~4,291,529 rows and 2.9 GiB
```

What can I do to prevent this? is there any way to change cache strategy for menu items? or simply I should EMPTY this table every week?

Comment: Isn't the question, why is your menu_cache so large in the first place? I don't have a habit of checking the cache table sizes, but I'm surprised that you have so many entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a bug in Drupal, but should be corrected since Drupal version 7.13. See more details here: http://drupal.org/node/1234830

As a workaround, you can empty (truncate) the cache_menu table, since it is just a cache table and will be regenerated. Of cource, you'll have a trade-off in performance, in that case.